# How do I read a large multiple csv file with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, memory, chunks

I am trying to read a large CSV files (aprox. 4 GB) in pandas and i am getting a memory error:

I have around 20-30 CSV files there, Each one file as Approx 277738 rows.

```
import glob
import pandas

folder_path = 'train/operations-data'
file_list = glob.glob(folder_path + "/*.csv")
main_df=pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(file_list[0]))

for i in range(1, len(file_list)):
    data = pd.read_csv(file_list[1])
    df=pd.DataFrame(data)
    main_dataframe = pd.concat([main_df,df],axis = 1)
    
print(main_df)
```

Any help on this?

Comment: What sort of help are you looking for exactly? It seems to me like you should either get more memory or look into a different solution, like Dask for example.

Answer (score 1):

When you work with large CSV files, memory errors can occur if you try to load the entire file into memory at once. To avoid this, modify your code to read and process the CSV files in smaller chunks.

Example using the chunksize parameter in `pd.read_csv()`:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

folder_path = 'train/operations-data'
file_list = glob.glob(folder_path + "/*.csv")

# Initialize an empty list to store the chunked dataframes
dfs = []

for file in file_list:
    # Read the CSV file in chunks
    reader = pd.read_csv(file, chunksize=10000)  # Adjust the chunksize as per your memory capacity
    
    # Iterate through each chunk and append it to the list
    for chunk in reader:
        dfs.append(chunk)

# Concatenate all the chunks into a single dataframe
main_df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)

print(main_df)
```

The chunk-size parameter is set to (e.g., 10000) that fits within your memory capacity. Adjust this value based on your available resources.

Instead of loading the entire CSV file into memory at once, `pd.read_csv()` reads the file in chunks.

Each chunk is stored in the dfs list.

`pd.concat()` is used to concatenate all the chunks into a single dataframe (main_df).